# switching one database platform to another database in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm working in a application which uses the database **POSTGRESQL**. As per recent recommendations, the same application pointed to **MYSQL** by changing data source in application.properties. So, this activity may repeat in future also.

I don't want to change application.properties every time. I need to switch **POSTGRES** to **MYSQL**.
In Hibernate, we can achieve this by configuring two mapping files. Like this, can we achieve this in spring boot?

Any Suggestions or examples are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use profiles in Spring for this.

Create a `application-postgresql.properties` file and a `application-mysql.properties` file, each with the corresponding JDBC url. Then start your application with either the `postgresql` or `mysql` profile.

See https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-profiles/ for more info.